# Overload the class itself

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Assume i have a class:

```
class foo
{
    ....
    //some constructors here set val=34
    ....
    private:
    int val;
    int & foo::operator,()
    {
      return val;
    }
};
```

and i want to be able to use it as:

```
foo bar;
printf("  %d ", bar);   //i need to get value of bar.val
                        //with just using bar itself with
                        //using an overloading
                        //but , overloading does not work
                        //i need to get 34 without using bar.val
                        //i need this without any getter 
                        //i need val to be private
```

Question: Is this kind of overloading possible? If yes, how?

I tried:

```
int foo::operator int()
{
    return val;
}
```

but it says "return type may not be specifiet on a conversion function" :(

I tried:

```
operator int() const { return val; }
```

conversion works only outside of printf & cout.

```
 int e=foo;
 printf(" %d ",e); //works
```

Comment: `operator int()` should work. Conversion operator if you want terminology.

Comment: i got an error: return type may not be specified on a conversion function

Comment: printf isn't type safe.  Prefer cout.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık, Conversion operators have no return type. They should typically be marked `explicit` as well (at least in C++11) and be a logical conversion.

Comment: Isnt there a null operator or something that just using the class-object's name is enough to use that overloading?

Comment: @chris, why `explicit` by default? A I understand it, having it explicit e.g. prevents `foo f; if (f == 3.0) …` since the explicit keyword will prevent subsequent conversion from int to double. I'd use `explicit` for boolean conversions, to avoid surprises by the bool-to-int cast, but otherwise I see no reason to advise them in general.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık, if you want `bar.val` whenever you write `bar`, why use a class in the first place. From this you see that there have to be some cases where you access the object without conversion, and to distinguish these, there has to be some motivation to trigger a conversion.

Comment: I am tying about an auto-type-changing thing :) for a custom-smart pointer.

Comment: @MvG, It's just about being clear. If you have a wrapper of a type, an implicit conversion operator to that type is usually a good thing in my books. I agree explicit conversions might not make sense more than implicit ones when it comes to conversion operators (but keep in mind that it's been marked a good practice to tack it onto ctors by default), but sometimes it might not be a totally natural conversion, and if it isn't something the user would readily think of, it can really get in the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot overload a class, but you can use a conversion operator so that it will automatically convert to different types according to expected parameters in that context. In your case, as `val` is an `int`, you'd overload the conversion to `int` like this:

```
operator int() const { return val; }
```

Now wherever an `int` is required, and you provide a `foo`, this conversion is applied.

There are some limits. For example, if you pass `foo` to a function template where the type of the corresponding argument is generic, there will be no conversion in that place. The conversion also won't affect other expressions which don't enforce a type. As an example, if `f` is type `foo`, then `&f` will always be of type `foo*`, not `int*`. For most practical applications, all this is exactly what you need. But I believe that the C-style variadic `printf` is just such a case where there is no well-defined expected type. Better use a C++-style call, or an explicit cast `static_cast<int>(f)`.

If neither is acceptable for you, then you are into trouble: there is no way that the C++ logic can deduce the fact that you require an `int` here, simply because you included a `%d` in some string constants. The type conversion is a compile-time thing, whereas the interpretation of format strings is done at runtime (except when generating warnings the way e.g. gcc does). The compiler won't know what type that argument needs to be, therefor it won't know what conversion to execute, therefore you have to help him in some way.

As long as this `int val` is the only member of `foo`, and there are no virtual functions either in this class, and neithe ris there a base class with any data members or a virtula function, the memory layout of an object of class `foo` will usually be the same as that of a plain integer. This means that the untyped C-style `printf` won't be able to tell the difference, even without any conversion at all. But relying on this is really bad style, so I'd advise against making use of this.

Comment: Doesn't help for printf, which takes a variable argument list, so the compiler doesn't know it needs to convert.

Comment: gives error atom2.cpp(61): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
atom2.cpp(63): warning C4183: '$S1': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'

Comment: operator int() const { return val; } works when i use int m=foo;printf(" %d ",m); at least there is m=foo working. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not overload comma or something as terrible. `printf` has ellipsis parameter so it accepts anything you feed to it, you must make sure that what you provide is correct. Keep it simple:

```
class foo
{
    ....
    //some constructors here set val=34
    ....
private:
    int val;
public:
    int value()
    {
      return val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo bar;
    printf("  %d ", bar.value());   //you get value of bar.val
}
```

The `printf` does not call any operators on your bar (including conversion operators), so these do not help you. Even if you had `operator int()` you should still write it like:

```
    printf("  %d ", (int)bar);   //you get value of bar.val
```

That is not much better looking. Or even:

```
    printf("  %d ", +bar);   //you get value of bar.val
```

Most confusing.

Comment: Can i do something else without using a getter please?

Comment: Yes i provided few examples with operator int, but these are considered worse than explicit getter.

Comment: MvG's operator int() const { return val; } works when i use int m=foo;printf(" %d ",m); at least there is m=foo working. thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible.

First, the comma operator doesn't apply here because the comma is used for separating the printf arguments, which takes precedence over the comma being used as an operator.

Adding a conversion operator doesn't help because the declaration of printf is

```
printf(const char *,...);
```

Which means the compiler doesn't know what type the parameters should be (other than the first), so it won't do any conversion.

Comment: MvG's operator int() const { return val; } works when i use int m=foo;printf(" %d ",m); at least there is m=foo working. thanks